# only keep the first letter for strings in any field of a tab-delimited file

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I would like to having your helps on keeping only the first letter for any strings in fields of a tab-delimited file.

I think sed can do this job. I tried, but I failed. I expect to having your advice and directions.

Thanks in advance.

A dummy example:

my_file, (tab-delimited)

```
1   11656   TCAG    .   TCAG    TCAG    .   TCAG    TCAG    TCAG
1   11660   CT  .   CT  CT  .   CT  CT  CT
1   11662   ATGG    .   ATGG    ATGG    .   ATGG    ATGG    ATGG
1   11680   A   .   A   A   .   A   A   A
1   11732   C   .   C   C   .   C   C   T
1   11742   T   .   T   C   .   T   T   T
```

What I want:

```
1   11656   T   .   T   T   .   T   T   T
1   11660   C   .   C   C   .   C   C   C
1   11662   A   .   A   A   .   A   A   A
1   11680   A   .   A   A   .   A   A   A
1   11732   C   .   C   C   .   C   C   T
1   11742   T   .   T   C   .   T   T   T
```

Code I tested:

```
# (1) workable for only one string
echo abcd123 | sed 's/\([a-z]\).*/\1/'
# (2) not work for my data file
sed 's/\([a-z]\).*/\1/' my_file
sed 's/\([a-z]\).*/\1/g' my_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manny's solution but a bit more generic

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\)[A-Z]*/\1/g' my_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\([ATGC]\)[ATGC]*/\1/g' my_file
```

Of course, if you're working with more than ATGC, expand on both character sets.

I believe your problem with using `.*` is that it will take all the characters to the end of the line, replacing only the first occurrence of your modified sequence. By using a second `[ATGC]`, you're limiting your search string to just those sequences.

Comment: Dear Manny D, Thanks a lot for your kind correction and explanation.